# Calculating Probability of Earthquakes in a Four-Week Period Using Poisson Distribution in Octave

Tags: octave, probability, poisson, probability-theory

Question: In an area of a country, it is known that earthquakes occur 1.4 times in 8 days in an average sense since the dawn of history. However, there were 15 earthquakes in the last four
weeks. Calculate the probability of 15 and more earthquakes
occurring in four consecutive weeks. Write code in octave. Avoid using built in functions.
Here is my attempt at the code

```
clc

lambda = 1.4/8 % Average number of earthquakes in one day
mu = lambda * 28 % Expected number of earthquakes in four weeks
p=0

% Calculate the probability of 15 and more earthquakes occurring in four consecutive weeks
for i = 0:14
 p = (exp(-mu)*(mu^i))/ factorial(i)
end

b= (1-p)*100

disp(['The probability of 15 and more earthquakes occurring in four consecutive weeks is: ' num2str(b)]);
```

I have tried to use Poisson distribution method to solve this but I am getting the wrong output. My output is 0.018312, which I think is too small. I have tried changing the formula but I think I am calculating the lambda wrong. Also I have not used the inbuilt command since it is not allowed. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Looks like you forgot to add up the terms. Maybe you should consider writing it as: `pi = (expression with exp)` and then `p = p + pi`. I think the result you are showing is just `1 - p(14)` and not 1 minus sum of `p(0)` through `p(14)`. Also, the problem statement doesn't say to output a percentage, so I would omit the multiplication by 100. Hope this helps.

Comment: Agree with @RobertDodier, you need to sum up the probabilities. Right now you are throwing away all of the `p` calculations except for the last one.

Comment: I would also add that while you are to write your own code, it's usually fine to use built in functions to check your results. if i was learning expansions by writing my own `sin` function calculator, i'd probably compare `mysin(x)` outputs with the built-in `sin(x)`.